# OTP validation massage not show

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I want to send otp if wrong otp than show massage "OTP Not verified Successfully " alse "OTP  verified Successfully" show msg. but massage not show if otp is curect than update else not update is working.
please help ....

**javaScript/Ajax**

```
    function otp_mobile_verify() {

         var verify_otp_number = $("#verify_otp_number").val();
         if (verify_otp_number) {
             $.ajax({
             url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>otp_mobile_verify_code",
             data: "verify_otp_number=" + verify_otp_number,
             type: "post",
             success: function(response) {

               $('#msg1').html(response);

               }

    });
   } 
 }
```

**Welcome controller**

```
  public function otp_mobile_verify_code()
      {
        $db2 = $this->load->database('dpr',TRUE);
        $otp = $this->input->post('verify_otp_number');
        $today_date = date('d-m-Y');
        $result =$db2->query('UPDATE dpr_book_appointment SET OTP_verified="Y" WHERE OTP_verified="'.$otp.'"');
        $data = $result->result_array();
        $dbotp = $data[0]["OTP_verified"];
            if ($result->num_rows() > 0) 
            { 
                if($otp==$dbotp)
                {

                    echo "OTP verified Successfully";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "OTP Not verified Successfully";
                }
            }
            echo json_encode($result);

    }
```

**view page**

Answer (score 0):

May be problem lies with this,

```
$result =$db2->query('UPDATE dpr_book_appointment SET OTP_verified="Y" WHERE OTP_verified="'.$otp.'"');
$data = $result->result_array();
```

You are updating record here so $result will return only boolean value i.e. true or false.
Thus $data doesn't contain any array and $dbotp cannot hold any value. You might be getting error just debug and check your Network tab in inspector.

Comment: please share valuable idea sir?

Comment: Need more clarity on this. Are you storing otp in OTP_verified column? And then after comparison you are changing it as 'Y'. Is it like this?

Comment: If yes, then, you can user select query instead of update. Fetch otp from db and compare it with user's entered otp. If matches, then use your update query to set flag as 'Y' exactly avove this line 'OTP verified Successfully'. Just don't use this $data = $result->result_array(); because we don't use it in update or insert query. User it in your select query.